# Easy way to split string into map in go

Tags: parsing, dictionary, go

I have such string:

```
"k1=v1; k2=v2; k3=v3"
```

Is there any simple way to make a `map[string]string` from it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use a couple of calls to `strings.Split()`:

```
s := "k1=v1; k2=v2; k3=v3"

entries := strings.Split(s, "; ")

m := make(map[string]string)
for _, e := range entries {
    parts := strings.Split(e, "=")
    m[parts[0]] = parts[1]
}

fmt.Println(m)
```

The first call will separate the different entries in the supplied string while the second will split the key/values apart. A working example can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/fPS7Fv2J5TB).

Comment: But what if the value contains "=" as well?

Comment: @ND003 then you would require a tokenizer. Take an example from how the Go team reads a tag from a struct field in `reflect.StructTag.Lookup`.